# Sort JSON Z-A on alternate clicks

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

I have a function to sort a JSON object that looks like this:

```
function compare(el1, el2, index) {
      return el1[index] == el2[index] ? 0 : (el1[index] < el2[index] ?-1 : 1);
   }
   array.sort(function(el1,el2){
      return compare(el1, el2, ""+thSortKey+"");
   });
```

The entire thing can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/unwsr/4/). This function is run when a table's `<th>` is clicked on. The way it's setup now allows for A-Z sorting, but on a second/alternate click I want to sort it from Z-A. The problem I'm running into is keeping track of the clicks. I tried using `.data()` to no avail, and `.toggle()` wouldn't work for me in this situation. My question is how do I keep track of clicks so that I can allow for Z-A sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try introducing a `dirCols` object with `key = headerName` and `value = direction`.

Then:

```
var dirCols = {};                          // <- added ... directions for columns
$('table tr th').live("click", function() {
  table = $('<table border="1"><tr>'+headersString+'</tr>');
  var thSortKey = $(this).text();
  var dir = dirCols[$(this).text()] || 1;  // <- added ... get previous dir or 1
  dirCols[$(this).text()] = -1 * dir;      // <- added ... save inverted dir
  function compare(el1, el2, index) {      // <- modified ... use dir in compare
    return el1[index] == el2[index] ? 0 : dir * (el1[index] < el2[index] ?-1 : 1);
  }
  // rest of the code
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/unwsr/9/) is the code.

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes to your fiddle that allows for sort tracking.  Notice the comments in the JavaScript code: http://jsfiddle.net/thejase/unwsr/16/

Furthermore, your sorted header will now have two CSS class hooks: .sortby for the sorting column and .reversed if it is reversed.

Comment: Every time I click on a `<th>` it alerts false.

Comment: Sorry, changed the link.  That was a debug version.